# How to resolve circular dependency where class uses static function but function takes instance as parameter?

Tags: python, oop, dependencies

I have a file games.py where I define a game class. This class has an instance method `some_function` which calls a static function `myfun`. `myfun` is defined in utils.py and I import it in the games.py file:

```
from utils.py import myfun

class Game:

    def some_function(self):
        ...
        myfun(self)
        ...
```

`myfun` takes as a parameter an object of type `Game`. I really like to use type hints in my code, so I define it like this:

```
from games.py import Game

def myfun(game: Game):
    ...
```

Unfortunately, I now get a circular dependency error. `Game` depends on `myfun` and `myfun` on `Game`.

I put `myfun` in the same file as `Game` and it seems to work then. However, I would like to keep things separate and `myfun` in the utils.py file. I would also really like to keep the type hinting. How could I resolve this issue?